# Pulling data from the database to a gridview with error code 413

Tags: asp.net

When I bind a datatable which contains: 183785 records from the database, I got this problem:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occured while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 413.

By searching around, the error indicates that:

"The status code 413 means that Request Entity Too Large.
The 413 status code indicates that the request was larger than the server is able to handle, either due to physical constraints or to settings. Usually, this occurs when a file is sent using the POST method from a form, and the file is larger than the maximum size allowed in the server settings."

But in the web.config, we already increase the maxRequestLength

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"/>
```

How can we fix this problem?

Comment: That's a `maxRequestLength` of only 2MB. Do you think that your 183,000+ records could be larger than 2MB? Does your table contain of lot of character data or XML? Are you selecting more from your database then you need to display?

Comment: Why are you getting that many records anyway? You are going to be about as popular as next door's dog after it took a dump in the middle of your lawn doing stuff like that.

Comment: it is stupid client. I asked them to reduce it but they said let it be like that :(

Comment: The value for the property 'maxRequestLength' is not valid. The error is: The value must be inside the range 0-2097151. Therefore, the max we can set is: 2097151

Comment: My bad, I think that value is set in kilobytes, giving yourself a 2GB maximum. Are you buy chance using any `UpdatePanel`s in your code?

Comment: Yes. I used UpdatePanel in mycode. is there something relevant with it? please give me a light then ;)

Comment: @devn: IIS 6.0 or 7+? The thread here may help you: http://forums.asp.net/p/1622363/4165500.aspx

Comment: @Cory it is 7+. So you suggest that I should incrase UploadReadAheadSize ?